# Installed Angular-cli but no angular?

Tags: angular

General info:

- OS: win 10 (both laptop and PC)
- Both Laptop and PC has node and npm installed
- Laptop and PC has Visual Studio Code

I installed Angular on my laptop without issues using "npm install -g @angular/cli" and using the command 'ng v' i was able to see the version of angular-cli, node, OS and Angular..

However doing the same on my other PC gives me this:
[Screen shot showing ng v being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etprK.png)

- Angular CLI: 1.7.3
- Node: 8.10.0
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: ...

I did the same in visual studio code but all it told me when looking for version was

- Angular: error

Not sure what to do to fix this, have been looking all over the interwebz but everyone talks about angular-cli.. not sure what the difference is yet since i just started working with it today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the CLI doesn't install any given version of angular; you have to create a new project first (which IIRC will run `npm install` for you). Only once `npm install` is run in an actual Angular project will Angular itself be downloaded/installed.

Comment: poked my way into the directory of the project i had cloned from github (Laptop) and typed the 'npm install' command in there.
it fixed the issue
Thanks

Comment: @Lardman glad to help! Note that `npm install` is the standard way of taking a new clone of a project and downloading any npm-based dependencies. It also needs to be run if another team member updates `package.json`. You will likely get used to having to run it manually on occasion in the future